# Real time values sent to unity webGl

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, real-time

I have a unity project the is deployed as webGl and added to my website that is hosted by azure. I need to send a live value from labview and check on this value to do some actions accordingly in my unity project.
I had an approach to send ah http request from labview with the value and an http get request from unity project but no result, not sure if i have done it correctly though.
Any other approaches or recommendations?

Comment: As far as i know you can't send post/get requests to a project without initiating it from the project, for example in your case you could send a requests to where the labview data is and then use the response with the labview data.

Comment: could you please explain more? I am new to this and can't get your point.

Comment: Check out the docs on WebRequests, I am sure you will understand more and come up with a solution, also in future please note that this site is for helping people with code not general questions on how to do something. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html